# How to merge two LINQ ToHashSet results?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a nested dictionary where I want to find all unique values of the second key.

I did this:

```
var x=new Dictionary<string k1, Dictionary<string k2, string value>>();
x.fill();

var hashsets = x.Values.Select(i => i.Keys).ToHashSet();

var res=new HashSet<string>();
foreach (var hs in hashsets) res.UnionWith(hs);
```

Is there a way to calculate res in a single linq statement (without the foreach) ?

Comment: Either use Aggregate to combine the sets, or use SelectMany to first flatten the sets and then call ToHashSet.

Comment: thanks ckuri, can you post an answer with example please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just reiterating what @ckuri said:

1st method to use Aggregate:

```
var result2 = x.Values.Aggregate(new HashSet<string>(), (rs, dic) => { rs.UnionWith(dic.Keys); return rs; });
// meaning: initialize the result with new HashSet<string>
// have the result to do union with each dictionary.keys
```

2nd method to use SelectMany:

```
var result2 = x.Values.SelectMany(i => i.Keys).ToHashSet();
// flatten the dictionary keys into IEnumerable<string>
// turn that into HashSet
```

Note: Some people might not understand your initial code, because it is not compile-able and you are missing minimal code. I believe there should be `ToHashSet()` extension method to make this working. Just for reference:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        return new HashSet<T>(source, comparer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for writing it down in detail. As a side note: I haven't measured it but I would guess the first one is more performant as it uses a method (UnionWith) specialized on combining sets of any size in an efficient manner.